# How to center the image of unknown size inside div?

Tags: css, alignment, vertical-alignment

Assume that I have a `div` having the following styles:

```css
#container {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Also I have an image of unknown size (the size may vary), which I want to  align both vertically and horizontally.

What is the best way of doing that?

Comment: Perhaps your CSS has a typo, but I want to make sure you understand that your class selector should be preceded by a dot, as in `.container { ... } `

Comment: Of course, I know this :)
my #container is not a class, it's id.

Comment: If it's an id, then you should preface it with #, as you do in your comment. I'm just saying.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The background image method will work, with background-position:center center, unfortunately you'll lose control of scaling your image.

You can set your image as follows:

```
position:absolute;
margin:auto;
top:0;
bottom:0;
left:0;
right:0;
```

PS. Keep in mind that this will be centered relative to its closest *positioned* parent.

Comment: Works for an image, but does not work for a DIV.  Seem to require hard-coded CSS width/height to center it.  Notice how if you remove the style attribute and leave only the HTML width/height on the div, it fails to center.  No so for the img tag.  Why this inconsistency?  https://jsfiddle.net/L1rk46xy/

Comment: perfect. dynamic.

Answer (score 4):

Add the following:

The first two lines center it vertically, the last horizontally.

```
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle ;
text-align: center;
```

more info can be  found here: http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center

Answer (score 0):

The easiest cross-browser way would be to set your dynamic image as a background property on the `#container`:

```
<div id="container" style="background: url(path/to/image.png) no-repeat 50% 50%"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will center vertically and horizontally.

```
#container {
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: table-cell;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nfBDT/

Answer (score 0):

i believe the easiest way is to do this:

```
.container img {
    display:block;
    margin:auto;
}
```

adjust .container to suit your div (not sure if yours was a class or ID)

oh I didn't read all of your question.

this appears to work:

```
<style type="text/css">
.wraptocenter {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: ...;
    height: ...;
}
.wraptocenter * {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
/*\*//*/
.wraptocenter {
    display: block;
}
.wraptocenter span {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 1px;
}
/**/
</style>
<!--[if lt IE 8]><style>
.wraptocenter span {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
}
</style><![endif]-->
```

full credit: http://www.brunildo.org/test/img_center.html

Answer (score 0):

http://zoffix.com/new/absolute-center-random-width-height.html

This is a pretty decent example. Usually you use table/vertical-align for modern browsers and positioning+%s for IE.